# An extensive project: Streaming audio from microphone to Android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, audio-streaming, android-bluetooth, android-audiorecord

I want to  take audio input from a Bluetooth microphone and stream it out loud--like a megaphone or a simple PA system--**and broadcast it in real-time**.

For this purpose I am using the AudioRecord and AudioTrack classes--since MediaRecorder and MediaPlayer writes and reads to an external file, which I could imagine delays the audio much more than necessary (is this true?).

I have discarded the idea of using any Bluetooth classes since the Android API doesn't support the Android device as a Sink in a Source/Sink-scenario (at least not yet) and would then require native programming of the Android libraries (this is also true, right?)

**Now. The app is working**, but **the delay is way too long** and the app is suppose to play audio in actual real-time.

My first question is: Are AudioRecord/AudioTrack the right classes for this purpose (streaming audio through a Bluetooth microphone to the device speakers and play it out loud in real-time)?

And if so: **How can I diminish  the delay on the audio** so that it streams the audio from a microphone in **actual real-time?** The whole code listed here, so please help yourself:

In Manifest, a permission for recording audio is required.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

I have a  dedicated class which extends a Thread for handling audio here:

```
public class AudioStreamer extends Thread {

/**
 * @Params:
 */
private int audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
private int sampleRate = 11025;
private int streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
private int mode = AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM;
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

private int channelConfigIn = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private int channelConfigOut = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;

private int recordSize;
private int trackSize;

private AudioTrack track;
private AudioRecord recorder;

/**
 * Initializes the un-initialized params: buffer, bufferSize, track and recorder
 * starts recording/playing with AudioRecord and AudioTrack respectively
 */
public AudioStreamer() {
    System.out.println("New code!");

    recordSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
            channelConfigIn, audioFormat);
    System.out.println("recordSize: "+recordSize);
    trackSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
            channelConfigOut, audioFormat);
    System.out.println("trackSize: "+trackSize);

    recorder = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRate,
            channelConfigIn, audioFormat, recordSize);

    if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
        track = new AudioTrack(streamType, sampleRate,
                channelConfigOut, audioFormat, trackSize, mode);

        if (track.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
            System.out.println("Record and Track initialized");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Track != init");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Recorder != init");
    }
}

/**
 * Runs thread--which reads and writes from/to the Android hardware
 */
public void run() {
    recorder.startRecording();
    track.play();

    if (recorder.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING
            && track.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING) {
        System.out.println("Recorder and track playing");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Track and recorder != PLAYING");
    }

    short[] buffer = new short[recordSize];
    int audioLenght = 0;

    while (recorder.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING
            && track.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING) {
        audioLenght = recorder.read(buffer, 0, recordSize);
        track.write(buffer, 0, audioLenght);
    }
}

/**
 * sets up the AudioManager for bluetooth audio streaming
 */
public void setAudioManager(AudioManager manager) {
    manager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

    // set true and test
    manager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
    manager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    System.out.println("bluetoothScoOn: " + manager.isBluetoothScoOn()
            + ", bluetoothA2DP: " + manager.isBluetoothA2dpOn()
            +", speakerPhone: "+manager.isSpeakerphoneOn());

    /**
     * Start BluetoothSCO
     */
    if (manager.isBluetoothA2dpOn()) {
        manager.startBluetoothSco();
        System.out.println("BtSco started");
    }
}

/**
 * Pauses the audio stream
 */
public void pause() {
    if (recorder.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
        recorder.stop();
    }

    if (track.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING) {
        track.pause();
        track.flush();
    }

    if (track.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PAUSED
            && recorder.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED) {
        System.out.println("Stopped");
    }
}

}
```

And my Main class is provided with clickable buttons that call start/stop-methods on the audio stream:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private AudioStreamer audioStreamer;
private AudioManager manager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    System.out.println("Program running ... ");
    audioStreamer = new AudioStreamer();

    manager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioStreamer.setAudioManager(manager);
}

public void startAudioStreamer(View view) {
    audioStreamer.start();
}

public void pauseAudioStreamer(View view) {
    audioStreamer.pause();
}

}
```

Which are displayed through a graphical layout with buttons like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.android.audiorecordrevisited.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startAudioStreamer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="startAudioStreamer"
    android:text="Start AudioStreamer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopAudioStreamer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/startAudioStreamer"
    android:onClick="pauseAudioStreamer"
    android:text="Stop Audio recording" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**How can I diminish the delay on the audio stream?** Am i using the correct classes, or is there another/better approach to this problem?

Also: The audio input doesn't seem to come through the actual Bluetooth microphone but instead from the Android hardware microphone--which isn't the idea. **How can I direct reading the audio input to the Bluetooth microphone instead of reading off the internal one?**

Comment: Could you quantify "way too long" for us?

Comment: Yes, of course. "Way too is long is" > 400 ms.

Comment: What's your "minBufferSize?" At 11k sample rate, 400ms equals a 4K buffer. You need to reduce that size.

Comment: where are you now on this question ?  get something running in real time ?

Comment: @ScottStensland nope, unfortunately I didn't